(Postfix) set rate_delay for 2 sending domains to 1 receiving domain
Currently I own 2 sender domains aaa.com and bbb.com. The restriction is that:

Each domain can only send one email after another with a delay of 200 seconds.
Each domain can only send 100 emails within 24 hours.

The following main.cf config is not applicable if I want to send emails from both domains  to a single receiving domain at the same time, since all emails will be pending at one queue instead of two (per sending domains).
default_destination_rate_delay=200s
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = 2
smtp_extra_recipient_limit = 100

Is there any solution for this kind of condition?

Find a solution by using Transport Map as below:

Edit the master.cf and add SMTP transports.
aaa unix - - n - - smtp
bbb unix - - n - - smtp


Create a transport file to map a domain with it’s transport name.
@aaa.com     :aaa
@bbb.com     :bbb


Add the policy to the main.cf
default_destination_rate_delay=0
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 2

sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
aaa_destination_rate_delay=200s
bbb_destination_rate_delay=200s


Reload postfix to make changes
postmap /etc/postfix/transport
postfix reload



